# How to add coordinate restrictions to an image

Tags: objective-c

I have 2 buttons that i hold down and they move an image across the screen, left or right, i want he image to stop at the edge of the screen though and not be able to move any further, i am at a loss for how to add the code to do that though.

```
    -(IBAction)Left:(id)sender{
    [MenuClick play];
    LeftTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(GoLeft) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    if (Left == nil) {
        LeftTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(GoLeft) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

-(IBAction)StopLeft:(id)sender{
    [LeftTimer invalidate];
    LeftTimer = nil;
}

-(IBAction)Right:(id)sender{
    [MenuClick play];
    RightTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(GoRight) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    if (Right == nil) {
        RightTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(GoRight) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

-(IBAction)StopRight:(id)sender{
    [RightTimer invalidate];
    RightTimer = nil;
}

-(void)GoLeft{
    Ship.center = CGPointMake(Ship.center.x -5, Ship.center.y);
}

-(void)GoRight{
    Ship.center = CGPointMake(Ship.center.x +5, Ship.center.y);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited in base at the comments

```
- (void)moveLeft
{
    CGPoint newCenter = ship.center;

    if (CGRectGetMinX(ship.frame)-5 <= 0)
    {
        newCenter.x=ship.bounds.size.width/2.0;
        [self stopLeft:nil];
    }
    else
    {
       center.x-=5;
    }
    ship.center = newCenter;
}


- (void)moveRight
{
    CGPoint newCenter = ship.center;

    if (CGRectGetMaxX(ship.frame)+5 >= self.view.bounds.width)
    {
        newCenter.x=self.view.bounds.width-ship.bounds.size.width/2.0;
        [self stopRight:nil];
    }
    else
    {
       center.x+=5;
    }
    ship.center = newCenter;
}
```

Comment: This will only move the ship by 5 once and then stop as the ship's frame will be intersecting the view's bounds.

Comment: You are right, I should use : 
`if ( !CGRectContainsRect(self.view.bounds,ship.frame) )`

Comment: Actually this will still move the ship beyond the screen bounds by 5  as it sets `ship.center` before it performs the check, which is essentially what my answer does, except it performs the calculation itself rather than relying on `CGRectContainsRect`.

Comment: thank you both for the help, both answers gave me the desired effect

Answer (score 1):

Update the `GoLeft` and `GoRight` methods to check the position of the image against the bounds of the view.

Assuming `self` is a `UIViewController` representing the screen...

```
-(void)GoRight{
    CGPoint proposedOrigin = CGPointMake(Ship.center.x +5, Ship.center.y);
    CGRect screenFrame = self.view.frame;

    // The ship's origin + width gets the right-most point,
    // compare this against the main view's width to determine
    // whether or not it should be moved.
    if (proposedOrigin.x + Ship.frame.size.width/2.0 < screenFrame.size.width) {
        Ship.center = proposedOrigin;
    } else {
        [self StopRight:nil];
    }
}
```

I'll leave it up to you to figure out the (easier) `GoLeft` modifications.

Comment: Since you are using the center coordinate and not the bottom right of the origin, shouldn't it be Ship.frame.size.width/2.0 ? Otherwise half of the image will be moved off the right side of the window.